# Convert String to Mat Java

Tags: java, android, string, converters, mat

I have a String saved that is full with Keypoints, but I need to use this string in the descriptor, which only takes Mat. How can I change my String to a Mat?

```
 String log = "[KeyPoint [pt={123.0, 164.0}, size=7.0, angle=-1.0, response=214.0, octave=0, class_id=-1], KeyPoint [pt={212.0, 170.0}, size=7.0, angle=-1.0, response=201.0, octave=0, class_id=-1], KeyPoint [pt={59.0, 116.0}, size=7.0, angle=-1.0, response=200.0, octave=0, class_id=-1], KeyPoint [pt={296.0, 133.0}, size=7.0, angle=-1.0, response=199.0, octave=0, class_id=-1]";
```

So if I could just change it from the String to the Mat, that would be perfect

Comment: can you post an example of the String ?

Comment: [KeyPoint [pt={123.0, 164.0}, size=7.0, angle=-1.0, response=214.0, octave=0, class_id=-1], KeyPoint [pt={212.0, 170.0}, size=7.0, angle=-1.0, response=201.0, octave=0, class_id=-1], KeyPoint [pt={59.0, 116.0}, size=7.0, angle=-1.0, response=200.0, octave=0, class_id=-1], KeyPoint [pt={296.0, 133.0}, size=7.0, angle=-1.0, response=199.0, octave=0, class_id=-1]
This is what is inside the string (it are keypoints)